# INSERT INTO a Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to simply adding some data in a table but I receive an error:

```
Msg 110, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.
```

Here what I'm using

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ReModalities
(ModalityId, Name, Description)
VALUES
(
    1,'A','A.',
    2,'B','B.'
);
```

This should give you an idea of the Table Column

```
INSERT INTO [XXX].[dbo].[ReModalities]
           ([ModalityId]
           ,[Name]
           ,[Description])
     VALUES
           (<ModalityId, int,>
           ,<Name, nvarchar(64),>
           ,<Description, nvarchar(256),>)
GO
```

Also I would like to know if there is  way I can avoid typing the IDs (the table has PK so they should be created automatically) many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Each row of the `values` statement should be enclosed in parenthesis.  Try:

```
VALUES
    (1,'A','A.'),
    (2,'B','B.');
```

If the ID has a default value or is an `identity`, you can omit it:

```
insert  dbo.ReModalities
        (Name, Description)
values  ('A','A.'),
        ('B','B.');
```